# How to Make an AJAX Get Request using MVC 3.0 RAZOR?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the below code which runs when an option in the drop down list is changed:

```
function ddlSqlList_onchange(listItemId) {
    $.get('/SqlReportList/SqlQuery',         
    { 
        "listItemId": listItemId 
    },
    function (data) { 
        alert('succeeded'); 
        $('#tbSqlQuery').text(data); 
    });}
```

"SqlReportList" is my Controller, SqlQuery is an Action and listItemId is an input parameter for that action.

```
     public string SqlQuery(string listItemId)
            {
// code here
}
```

It works locally fine but when deployed unto our dev server, it doesn't work.

I realized that the URL has to change to "/ApplicationName/SqlReportList/SqlQuery" to make it work on the server.

So how to retrieve the application path at runtime?

Comment: Please post your routes.

Comment: Try using the `@Url.Action()` helper.

Comment: Is your site deployed as a (virtual) application beneath another site in IIS?

Comment: @Magnus That would be my guess.

Comment: @Magnus, an Application yes. Not virtual directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of MVC are you using..

In MVC 3.0 with Razor you could use:

```
@Url.Action("SqlQuery","SqlReportList")
```

or you could use:

```
@Server.MapPath("~")
```

to get the base address of your app and then build it up yourself. Server.MapPath works in the controller too if that helps.(Seems the Url class is available in the controller too)

(from memory)

edit for comment:

If you are in a .cshtml file it would look like the following:

```
function ddlSqlList_onchange(listItemId) {
    $.get('@Url.Action("SqlQuery","SqlReportList")',         
    { 
        "listItemId": listItemId 
    },
    function (data) { 
        alert('succeeded'); 
        $('#tbSqlQuery').text(data); 
    });}
```

Comment: The OP could be using unobtrustive JavaScript (hopefully) in which case you can't put Razor code in it.

Comment: @Shark good shout.. in that case could you not use a razor page to generate the JS file? otherwise are you stuck with having separate JS files for each deployment location? (maybe i am missing something i am no expert ;-)

Comment: @gordatron, I'd need that to be written inside a javascript function. I don't think that's possible with your code?

Comment: @William I updated the answer to show what it would look like though i have not tested this

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to write inline JavaScript that much then you could store url to hidden field like this.

```
<input type="hidden" id="myGetUrl" value="@(Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller"))" />
```

Inside your JavaScript

```
function ddlSqlList_onchange(listItemId) {
    var url = $('#myGetUrl').val();
    $.get(url,         
    { 
        "listItemId": listItemId 
    },
    function (data) { 
        alert('succeeded'); 
        $('#tbSqlQuery').text(data); 
    }
);}
```

Comment: I'd need to use few more actions, that wouldn't be nice to use hidden controls for each. Would that be possible to write RAZOR code inside javascript?

Comment: @William It's possible, but then you must write inline JavaScript which means that JavaScript is inside your Razor file. This leads to problems if you want re-use your JavaScript code in some other context.

Comment: @William You could use gordatron's answer, so that only Server.MapPath("~") would be in the hidden field (maybe even in the Layout file). In JavaScript you could combine that with your action. $('#path').val() + "Controller/Action"

Answer (score 0):

if you're using ASPX, you use the following :

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '<%=Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")%>',
   data: { dataNameInAction: dataValue },
   success: function () {
         callBack Success Function
   },
   error: function () {
         callbackFaileFunction
   }
});
```

and on the serverSide ( Controller )

you return the JsonData back if you're dealing with Json,

e.g.

```
public ActionScript Action(DataType dataNameInAction)
{
..
..

return Json(new { ReturnedData = value, ReturnedData2 = value2 });
}
```

I Hope This Helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.hostname` and workout the url from there.